# MVC not rebuilding after model changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this build error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Timesheet.Models.Time' does not contain a definition for 'Hours' and no extension method 'Hours' accepting a first argument of type 'Timesheet.Models.Time' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
...
Line 36:                 <td class="text-right">@String.Format("{0:N2}", client.Projects.SelectMany(project => project.Times).Sum(time => time.Hours))</td>
```

Despite having this in the model:

```
public Decimal Hours
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDateTime(Minutes).TotalHours);
    }
}
```

Basically, I've just replaced a Start & End time with a Minutes field, and updated the Hours definition to use the Minutes instead of calculating from Start & End times (and renamed it from HoursSpent to just Hours). But these changes in the model are not 'building' properly.

In fact, if I check the intellisense on Line 36 of the model, I see the old fields. If I hit F12 on the HoursSpent, it takes me to "Time [from metadata]", and not to the Time model. So the build is not building.

Comment: Don't you need a setter for hours because of sum?

Comment: Could you provide the entire Time model?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was I had opened the project from Local IIS and something was a bit screwy. I rebooted and re-opened from the file system and that seemed to fix the problem.